# Как в админке реализовать html редактор?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, express, backend, nextjs

Возникла проблема. Я использую react(nextjs) и mongoDB. У меня есть админка для сайта (сам делаю). В ней есть возможность редактировать, создавать и удалять посты для сайта. Все это я сохраняю потом в базу данных. При создании поста я заполняю несколько полей (описание небольшое, тайтл, рейтинг и еще несколько полей). Еще один пункт при созздани поста - это добавление произвольного html кода (статья со списками, ссылками, картинками и т.д.). Вот я не могу понять, как я могу добавлять этот код в админке. С возможностью загрузки картинок, html кода, добавлением каких-либо компонентов  и т.д. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить этот вопрос?

Comment: Например можно скармливать дочерний компонент с нужными тегами.

Comment: Можно пример? Не представляю пока как это

Comment: Кидаете jsx или чистый html пропсом и рендерите его внутри компонента.